# Count how many times a word exist in column

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2016

I have a table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
INSERT INTO table1 values('XYZ')
INSERT INTO table1 values('ABC')
INSERT INTO table1 values('XYZ~ABC~AAA')
INSERT INTO table1 values('123')
```

Then, I have string 'ABC~XYZ~123'. I need to split this string into each word by using SQL:

```
Select VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT('ABC~XYZ~123','~')
```

The return is table2

```
ABC
XYZ
123
```

I want to count how many times each word in table2 existed in table 1

The expected output is

```
ABC|3
XYZ|2
123|1
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Have you considered using the aptly named function, `COUNT`?

Comment: You should seriously give consideration to moving away from storing multiple `~` separate values in a single record.  _Normalize_ your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your case correctly, the next statement may help:

Text and table:

```
DECLARE @text varchar(100) = 'ABC~XYZ~123'
CREATE TABLE Data (
   Id int,
   [Text] varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO Data
   (Id, [Text])
VALUES
   (1, 'XYZ'),
   (2, 'ABC'),
   (3, 'XYZ~ABC~AAA'),
   (4, '123~ABC')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT t.[value] AS [Word], j.[Count]
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@text, '~') t
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT s.[value], COUNT(*) AS [Count]
   FROM Data d
   CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(d.[Text], '~') s
   GROUP BY s.[value]
) j ON t.[value] = j.[value]
```

Result:

```
-----------
Word  Count
-----------
ABC   3
XYZ   2
123   1
```

Comment: @HungNguyen You should accept the best working solution suitable for you as it also helped others to find the answer quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the suggestions as in comment you can use [Count()](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-aggregate-functions/sql-server-count/) function as below. But storing in this format will give you difficulty for the extraction as well as in join with the other tables.

```
Select T1Value, Count(*) as [NoCount] from(
 Select table1.Value as T1Value, Value FROM STRING_SPLIT('ABC~XYZ~123','~')
 inner join table1 on Value = table1.Value
)a group by T1Value
```

**Edit**

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
  TableValue varchar(max)
);

INSERT INTO table1 (TableValue) values ( 'XYZ');
INSERT INTO table1 ( TableValue) values ( 'ABC');
INSERT INTO table1 ( TableValue) values ( 'XYZ~ABC~AAA');
INSERT INTO table1 ( TableValue) values ( '123~ABC');

SELECT b.value
    ,Count(*)
FROM (
    SELECT VALUE
    FROM STRING_SPLIT('ABC~XYZ~123', '~')
    ) a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM table1
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(TableValue, '~')
    ) b ON a.Value = b.Value
GROUP BY b.Value
```

Here is the given [Live Demo on db <> fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=377b25e14beec01acce75b7ab1c55b6c)

Comment: It's not what i means. Because I have a table and a string.
What I need to do is:
1. split string into seperate word
2. count how many times each word existed in provided table.

Comment: @HungNguyen If you have clear idea about the joins and count then you can get it done easily. I have given an idea to solve your problems.

Comment: I've updated my post to make it clearer. Please refer above

Comment: @HungNguyen Please check the edited version of answer and request you to update the create table syntax with proper one in your question body.

Answer (score 0):

Setup

```
create table STRINGS (ID int, STRINGS varchar(max));

insert into STRINGS (ID, STRINGS) values (1, 'XYZ');
insert into STRINGS (ID, STRINGS) values (1, 'ABC');
insert into STRINGS (ID, STRINGS) values (1, 'XYZ~ABC~AAA');
insert into STRINGS (ID, STRINGS) values (1, '123~ABC');

declare @VALUES varchar(max) = 'XYZ~ABC~123';
```

Calculation :

```
select V1.VALUE, count(STRINGS.ID) 
from string_split(@VALUES,'~') V1
     cross join STRINGS
     outer apply string_split(STRINGS.STRINGS,'~') V2
where V2.VALUE = V1.VALUE     
group by V1.VALUE
```

Result

```
-----------
Value Num
-----------
ABC   3
XYZ   2
123   1
```

Live exemple : 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=15b95efcf69ea98fafbb7dda1c624551